# Groovy Script Execution Exception

Tags: elasticsearch

Can anyone tell me what approach I need to take to solve the below exception?

```
[2017-05-23 15:28:48,783][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Mister Buda] [2217] Failed to execute fetch phase
org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptExecutionException: NullPointerException[null]
    at org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:274)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.script.ScriptFieldsFetchSubPhase.hitExecute(ScriptFieldsFetchSubPhase.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.FetchPhase.execute(FetchPhase.java:194)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeFetchPhase(SearchService.java:516)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$17.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:452)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$17.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:449)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:559)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I see this exception during querying an index, that query contains a `script_field`.

I am using elasticsearch version 1.5.

This is the script,

```
(( _source.rating.'${amount}'.costRating.value * costWeighting) + ( _source.rating.flexibilityRating.value * (1 - costWeighting))) * 10
```

Here's the image of the sample data in the index,
 [image]

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to show your script :-)

Comment: @Val I have added the script.

Comment: Do all your documents have a `rating` and `costRating` fields? Where does `${amount} ` come from?

Comment: 1/ i think the problem is in '${amount}' because in groovy single quoted string is just a string. in this case it always equals to `${amount}`. if you want to present amount variable as a string - just double quote it.
`"${amount}"`

Comment: 2/ you can use `elvis operator` and `null safe accessor`.   ex: `_source?.rating?.flexibilityRating?.value ?: 0` . in this case `?.` will return null instead of throwing NullPointerException, and `?: 0` will return 0 if previous expression was false (null or zero)

Comment: I have attached sample data from the index. The `'${amount}'` gets translated to something like this, `(( _source.rating.'150000'.costRating.value * costWeighting) + ( _source.rating.flexibilityRating.value * (1 - costWeighting))) * 10` so I don't think that is an issue. Also, if something is missing it should show as part of the error. But, the error doesn't give me anything.

Comment: Thanks @daggett and @Val, I am able to solve it. It's actually null values in the documents. some amount tiers have costRating as null. `exists filter` helped me find null values in the document. Thanks for the suggestion to use `null safe` operator. It helped! Thanks again for your time.